# Which in-memory MongoDB implementation is good for unit and integration testing?

Tags: mongodb, in-memory-database

We are trying to move from Fongo to some other in-memory MongoDB service. We are looking for one from org.mongodb and haven't found one. This is our preference because this will have long term support from MongoDB org.

We found bwaldvogel/mongo-java-server. However, they may not support for latest MongoDB dependencies versions like Fongo.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can run MongoDB in tmpfs (or zram). Works very well.

Comment: We are looking to incorporate this in-memory MongoDB into Java JUnit testings.